# How to simplify Jquery from bootstrap modal and my custom toolbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

how can I simplify this few lines of code? I have hardcoded but I believe it can be made with less code.

Thanks!

```
// Additional toolbar with "close" button appears
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('modal').modal('show');
    $('#toolbar').css('display', 'block');
});

$(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('modal').modal('show');
    $('#toolbar').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best you can do to reduce the lines:

```
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('modal').modal('show');
    $('#toolbar').css('display', 'block');
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('modal').modal('show');
    $('#toolbar').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian for your effort!